# AngularJS directive, only render html for some tags

Tags: html, angularjs, directive

I have this text

```
<span class"mention">User</span> has a question: what does <h1>Head</h1> mean?
```

Do you have any idea to use `element.append` or `element.html` to render html for this text, but except `h1` and other tags?

Comment: This is not clear... What is our final goal ? Why do you need element.append and element.html ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Provide you expectation in detail

Comment: I have some reasons to render html by custom directive, so I have to `$compile` it on `link` function. `<span class"mention">User</span>` should be rendered and styled, but `h1` is content of question, so it should be rendered as normal text.